# Rails active record associations, nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

Been going through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html but can't seem to get my head around this

I have 4 models: users, listings, comments, commentresponses.  Somebody creates a listing, someone else can comment on the listing, then the original creator can respond to the comment.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: 'provider'
  has_many :listings
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commentresponses
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :listing
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :commentresponse
end

class Commentresponse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :comment
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Everything is working well except I can't access comment.commentresponse; this give a no method error.

Any recommendations of where my logic is wrong?

Comment: this code looks fine can you paste exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Associations**

I wouldn't use a separate model for `CommentResponse`; keep it all in the `Comment` model - using a gem such as [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to give a `parent` / `child` system to the different `comments`:

[image]

Above is an *example* of one our `Category` models - showing how you can order the different associations with the likes of the `ancestry` gem. The reason why I posted is because this is how you can create *responses* to your comments, rather than having a separate model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings
  has_many :comments
end

#app/models/listing.rb
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :listing
    belongs_to :user

    has_ancestry #-> make sure you have "ancestry" column with string in db
end
```

This basically allows you to use the [various methods](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree) which `ancestry` appends to your objects:

[image]

---

**Ancestry**

I would recommend using the Ancestry gem to store the responses of the comments. You can then add to this by using several `partials` to provide a nested interface. This way, it will show you the comments you want, with the correct responses etc

*IMPORTANT*

When using `ancestry` - you define the parents of the rows with `comment_1/comment_2`. Many people think you have to just define the "parent"; not true. You have to define the entire "history" of the ancestors of an object

--

**Tree**

If you go with the `ancestry` approach, you'll be able to do something like the following:

[image]

To achieve this, you can use the nested partial we created here (obviously replace for use with comments):

```
#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: @categories } %>

#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<ol class="categories">
    <% collection.arrange.each do |category, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <!-- Category -->
            <div class="category">
                <%= link_to category.title, edit_admin_category_path(category) %>
            </div>

            <!-- Children -->
            <% if category.has_children? %>
                <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
            <% end %>

        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

---

I know it's not a *direct* answer to your question; it certainly should help you though

Comment: +1 to not having a separate model for comment responses

Comment: Thanks - it's the best way

Comment: Thanks Rick, appreciate the recommendation.  I tool a look at ancestry.  In the case of multi-layered comments, would you then recommend the following: First comment: Comment.create(comment: "You failed").  First response: comment(1).children.create(comment: "No, I actually passed").  Second response (response to response): comment(2).children.create(comment: "nope, you really failed").  Etc?

Comment: Yep - that's the best way to do it I think

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Got things working with comment.children.create, but couldn't seem to make it work by creating a new comment and passing in :parent_id.  Either way, working solution, so thx again